# Remove lists of list that has a specific duplicate index without keeping the first one found and keeping order

Tags: python, duplicates

If I had a simple list of values I could totally remove the duplicates like this:

```
lines = ['a','b','a']

final_lines = [l for l in lines if lines.count(l) == 1]
```

Output:

```
['b']
```

But when I have list of lists and I want to specifically analise the index `[0]` for duplicate values and remove the lists if exist duplicate:

```
lines = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['a','j','k','l']]

final_lines = [l for l in lines if lines.count(l[0]) == 1]
final_lines = [l for l in lines if l[0].count(l[0]) == 1]
final_lines = [l for l in lines if l[0].count(lines[0][0]) == 1]
```

This option not returns this desired output:

```
[['e','f','g','h']]
```

**Info add:**

After creating the question I ended up bumping into a new attempt:

```
final_lines = [l for l in lines if l[0].count(lines[0][0]) == 0]
```

but only works if only one index repeat, if there one more like this:

```
lines = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['e','f','g','h'],['a','j','k','l']]
```

Instead of it returning:

```
[]
```

Return:

```
[['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach: use a list of what you want to compare for each item:

```
firsts = [x[0] for x in lines]

final_lines = [l for l in lines if firsts.count(l[0]) == 1]
```